# Run ViewDidLoad method on FlipViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, utility

I have a few settings in my flipviewcontroller utility application and when I click "Done" I want to be able to refresh the screen on the MainViewController. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what about viewWillApear? If you are using modalPresentation or push/pop viewController then it will be called and you can do your refreshing stuff here.

Comment: @Ravin thanks this is exactly what i needed. I didn't know I could do this since the code wasn't pre-made :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ravin is correct -- you should use `-viewWillAppear` rather than `-viewDidLoad`. `-viewDidLoad` is for initialization that has to be deferred until after the view is loaded; what you're talking about is an update that should happen whenever the view appears.

Comment: when does `-viewWillAppear` fire?

Comment: @cfarm54 Seriously? It seems pretty obvious given the name, but if you're not sure you could always [look at the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16).

Comment: Yeah I thought I knew when it would fire by the name, but I'm finding that it's firing 4x when I load my first screen.